# How to print Accuracy and other metrics in Tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow2.x

I am working on an object detection project with a custom dataset. My problem is that, it is really difficult to understand how and where should I make changes to evaluate my training set(accuracy, mAP metrics). I am using the tensorflow 2.3.0 on colab and for now I am getting only the loss value as it is shown in the following picture:
[image: loss].

Also, this is a picture of my tensorboard:
[image: tensorboard].

To train the model I use the model_main_tf2.py,

```
!python /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_file} \
    --model_dir={model_dir} \
    --alsologtostderr \
    --num_train_steps={num_steps} \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=10 \
    --eval_training_data=True \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=10 \
    --num_eval_steps={num_eval_steps}
```

In the configuration file I have:  `eval_config { metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics" use_moving_averages: false }`

I have tried various things, just like with eval.py (which I read works with tensorflow 1.x), but I encounter a lot of errors or just like with other scripts in the object detection repository from github, [object_detection(repository)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

The most important thing for now, is the accuracy. I found that the loss is probably defined at the model_lib_v2.py at 845-858 line:

```
 eval_metrics = {}

  for evaluator in evaluators:
    eval_metrics.update(evaluator.evaluate())
  for loss_key in loss_metrics:
    eval_metrics[loss_key] = loss_metrics[loss_key].result()

  eval_metrics = {str(k): v for k, v in eval_metrics.items()}
  tf.logging.info('Eval metrics at step %d', global_step)
  for k in eval_metrics:
    tf.compat.v2.summary.scalar(k, eval_metrics[k], step=global_step)
    tf.logging.info('\t+ %s: %f', k, eval_metrics[k])

  return eval_metrics
```

but I do not know how to change the code to add accuracy.

In case that helps, I use the ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640 model and gdrive to load the data and the run the scripts.

**Update:**
The config file I use is the following:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 18
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.009999999776482582
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.996999979019165
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
      }
      use_depthwise: true
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        additional_layer_depth: 128
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.75
        unmatched_threshold: 0.25
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.996999979019165
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
        }
        depth: 128
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
        share_prediction_tower: true
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 16
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.07999999821186066
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.026666000485420227
          warmup_steps: 1000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/deploy/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 20000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 1
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/deploy/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/data/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/deploy/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/data/test.record"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to have found the solution to your question. Thats great, but you just need to wait a little more to actually get evaludation metrics showing up in your tensorboard.

Start with the defaults and work your way up the training.

First run Training as a dameon:

```
!python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path={pipeline_file} \
--model_dir='object_detection/training' \
--alsologtostderr &
```

Then run Evaluation on a different console or shell. The evaluation will automatically pick up the newer checkpoints (by default this is at every 1000th step. So you gotta wait for training to reach 1000th step + wait for evaluation to complete 1 epoch or number of images in your test.record)

```
!python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path={pipeline_file} \
--model_dir='object_detection/training' \
--alsologtostderr \
--checkpoint_dir='object_detection/training'
```

Here's a sample configuration which you can use to visualise.

```
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1
  num_visualizations: 10
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 5
  visualize_groundtruth_boxes: true
  eval_interval_secs: 30
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "path/to/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: true
  queue_capacity: 100 #depending on your GPU/TPU/CPU
  num_epochs: 1 #what encompasses when to upload results for mAP and AR, if you rather have a number provide that under [num_examples <= test.record total size else error]
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "path/to/test.record"
  }
}
```

Quite a few things to note here: [TF20 issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8999)

```
batch_size: 1 #This has to be 1. TF2 throws errors
```

```
num_epochs: 1 #provide this as 1
```

```
eval_interval_secs: #something based on your dataset & gpu config. Default is 300
```

```
num_epochs: 1 #what encompasses when to upload results for mAP and AR, if you rather have a number provide that under [num_examples <= test.record total size else error]
```

Most importantly, wait. Wait for the evaluation to be complete atleast twice (the first time usually, it basically runs for step 0 which is useless (as your training has to reach a checkpoint (default as mentioned above at 1000th)))

Answer (score 1):

After trying with this piece of code:

```
!python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path={pipeline_file} \
--model_dir='object_detection/training' \
--checkpoint_dir='object_detection/training' \
--alsologtostderr
```

I eventually managed to get some results different from zero (maybe sth changed concerning the checkpoints). The results:

```
2020-09-20 10:11:00.899773: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
W0920 10:11:02.925597 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:925] Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: None
I0920 10:11:02.925838 140679676843904 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0920 10:11:02.925928 140679676843904 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
I0920 10:11:02.926012 140679676843904 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
W0920 10:11:02.926136 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:940] Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
2020-09-20 10:11:02.934837: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-09-20 10:11:02.971958: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:02.972512: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.73GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
2020-09-20 10:11:02.972554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-09-20 10:11:02.974022: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:02.975587: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:02.975923: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:02.980298: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:02.981636: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:02.985271: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-09-20 10:11:02.985387: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:02.985948: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:02.986434: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-20 10:11:02.991809: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2200000000 Hz
2020-09-20 10:11:02.991994: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x12e1480 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-20 10:11:02.992021: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-09-20 10:11:03.103553: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:03.104214: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x12e1640 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-20 10:11:03.104245: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla T4, Compute Capability 7.5
2020-09-20 10:11:03.104426: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:03.104982: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.73GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105024: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105075: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105097: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105121: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105140: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105158: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105181: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105258: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:03.105829: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:03.106297: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-20 10:11:03.106340: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-09-20 10:11:03.719107: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-20 10:11:03.719168: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-09-20 10:11:03.719181: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-09-20 10:11:03.719388: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:03.720044: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-20 10:11:03.720576: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2020-09-20 10:11:03.720625: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 13962 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0920 10:11:03.765423 140679676843904 dataset_builder.py:83] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W0920 10:11:03.768426 140679676843904 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:175: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0920 10:11:03.799010 140679676843904 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:175: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0920 10:11:07.302673 140679676843904 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py:259: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0920 10:11:08.378596 140679676843904 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py:259: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Waiting for new checkpoint at object_detection/training
I0920 10:11:10.765872 140679676843904 checkpoint_utils.py:125] Waiting for new checkpoint at object_detection/training
INFO:tensorflow:Found new checkpoint at object_detection/training/ckpt-7
I0920 10:11:10.769416 140679676843904 checkpoint_utils.py:134] Found new checkpoint at object_detection/training/ckpt-7
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:702: set_learning_phase (from tensorflow.python.keras.backend) is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11.
Instructions for updating:
Simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
W0920 10:11:10.791586 140679676843904 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:702: set_learning_phase (from tensorflow.python.keras.backend) is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11.
Instructions for updating:
Simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/eval_util.py:878: to_int64 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0920 10:11:51.835231 140679676843904 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/eval_util.py:878: to_int64 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
2020-09-20 10:11:56.921874: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-09-20 10:11:57.287284: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
INFO:tensorflow:Finished eval step 0
I0920 10:11:59.687197 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:799] Finished eval step 0
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py:617: py_func (from tensorflow.python.ops.script_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
tf.py_func is deprecated in TF V2. Instead, there are two
    options available in V2.
    - tf.py_function takes a python function which manipulates tf eager
    tensors instead of numpy arrays. It's easy to convert a tf eager tensor to
    an ndarray (just call tensor.numpy()) but having access to eager tensors
    means `tf.py_function`s can use accelerators such as GPUs as well as
    being differentiable using a gradient tape.
    - tf.numpy_function maintains the semantics of the deprecated tf.py_func
    (it is not differentiable, and manipulates numpy arrays). It drops the
    stateful argument making all functions stateful.
    
W0920 10:11:59.819776 140679676843904 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py:617: py_func (from tensorflow.python.ops.script_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
tf.py_func is deprecated in TF V2. Instead, there are two
    options available in V2.
    - tf.py_function takes a python function which manipulates tf eager
    tensors instead of numpy arrays. It's easy to convert a tf eager tensor to
    an ndarray (just call tensor.numpy()) but having access to eager tensors
    means `tf.py_function`s can use accelerators such as GPUs as well as
    being differentiable using a gradient tape.
    - tf.numpy_function maintains the semantics of the deprecated tf.py_func
    (it is not differentiable, and manipulates numpy arrays). It drops the
    stateful argument making all functions stateful.
    
INFO:tensorflow:Performing evaluation on 43 images.
I0920 10:12:04.423586 140679676843904 coco_evaluation.py:282] Performing evaluation on 43 images.
creating index...
index created!
INFO:tensorflow:Loading and preparing annotation results...
I0920 10:12:04.423980 140679676843904 coco_tools.py:116] Loading and preparing annotation results...
INFO:tensorflow:DONE (t=0.00s)
I0920 10:12:04.426340 140679676843904 coco_tools.py:138] DONE (t=0.00s)
creating index...
index created!
Running per image evaluation...
Evaluate annotation type *bbox*
DONE (t=0.17s).
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=0.04s).
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.728
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.999
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.806
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.728
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.784
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.784
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.784
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.784
INFO:tensorflow:Eval metrics at step 5000
I0920 10:12:04.649628 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:853] Eval metrics at step 5000
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.727510
I0920 10:12:04.672720 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.727510
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.999325
I0920 10:12:04.675546 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.999325
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU: 0.806042
I0920 10:12:04.676922 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU: 0.806042
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small): -1.000000
I0920 10:12:04.678196 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small): -1.000000
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (medium): -1.000000
I0920 10:12:04.679378 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (medium): -1.000000
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (large): 0.727510
I0920 10:12:04.680430 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (large): 0.727510
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1: 0.783721
I0920 10:12:04.681638 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1: 0.783721
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10: 0.783721
I0920 10:12:04.682775 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10: 0.783721
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100: 0.783721
I0920 10:12:04.683973 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100: 0.783721
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small): -1.000000
I0920 10:12:04.685043 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small): -1.000000
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (medium): -1.000000
I0920 10:12:04.686104 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (medium): -1.000000
INFO:tensorflow:    + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (large): 0.783721
I0920 10:12:04.687381 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (large): 0.783721
INFO:tensorflow:    + Loss/localization_loss: 0.089791
I0920 10:12:04.688443 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + Loss/localization_loss: 0.089791
INFO:tensorflow:    + Loss/classification_loss: 0.336598
I0920 10:12:04.689506 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + Loss/classification_loss: 0.336598
INFO:tensorflow:    + Loss/regularization_loss: 0.117549
I0920 10:12:04.690544 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + Loss/regularization_loss: 0.117549
INFO:tensorflow:    + Loss/total_loss: 0.543938
I0920 10:12:04.691550 140679676843904 model_lib_v2.py:856]  + Loss/total_loss: 0.543938
INFO:tensorflow:Waiting for new checkpoint at object_detection/training
I0920 10:16:10.791572 140679676843904 checkpoint_utils.py:125] Waiting for new checkpoint at object_detection/training
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 89, in main
    wait_interval=300, timeout=FLAGS.eval_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 966, in eval_continuously
    checkpoint_dir, timeout=timeout, min_interval_secs=wait_interval):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py", line 184, in checkpoints_iterator
    checkpoint_dir, checkpoint_path, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py", line 132, in wait_for_new_checkpoint
    time.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

However, tensorboard has not been updated with these metrics (AP, AR etc). Propably I am doing sth wrong. I still haven't made any progress regarding the *accuracy*, so if someone knows something, it would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your `eval_config` file? I had a similar issue and I fixed it by providing the values as per the dataset

Comment: Sure, I updated my question to include the config file. Actually, I also even tried with tensorflow 1.15 and ssd_mobilenet_v1, but again I find it complicated to make the appropriate changes so as to show the accuracy. Thanks! @papaya

Comment: Your evaluations happen till you reach 1 epoch, as per the eval_input_reader. Say you have 1000 images on your test.record (this directly gets loaded in to your memory. Consider giving a queue size). Now depending on how many steps that is once an initial checkpoint is made. You wont be able to get any kind of evaluation.